# IBM Watson Relationship Extraction "Forwarding error" (status_code 500)

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am POSTing a piece of text to IBM/Watson's Relationship Extraction service but get the following response after about 90 seconds:

> {"status": {"message": "Forwarding error", "status_code": 500}}

Most small files work fine and the results are as expected. However, this file is large (200k) in size.

Here's my code:

```
set_time_limit(0);

$curl = curl_init();
$post_args = array(
'txt' => $data,
'sid' => 'ie-en-news',
'rt' => 'json' 
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/relationship-extraction-beta/api/v1/sire/0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "XXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600); 

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$decoded = json_decode($result, true);
echo "RESPONSE: [<Br/><pre>$result</pre><br/>]";
```

I tried increasing the timeout values using `set_time_limit()`, `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` but that made no difference.

Comment: Should I be asking this question in another place? :) If yes, please advise.

Comment: How many characters and how many bytes is the text file you are trying to analyze?

Comment: Here is output from recent test.... Sending 254,618 bytes to Watson...
***ERROR*** [{"status": {"message": "Forwarding error", "status_code": 500}}]   Total Execution Time: 00:01:21 (hh:mm:ss). Oddly enough, when I get this error, it happens almost always at the 1 min 21 sec mark.

Comment: It would appear that the error is not a result of some file size limitation. Here is an example of error when file was about 25k. Sending 25,804 bytes to Watson... ***ERROR*** [{"status": {"message": "Forwarding error", "status_code": 500}}]   Total Execution Time: 00:01:20 (hh:mm:ss)

Comment: @WonkotheSane are you still having this issue?

Comment: Yes Jeff, it is still happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's an internal error when the service (in this case Visual Recognition) can't be found so the load balancer returns a http status 500 forwarding error.
It was probably a glitch in the network, the service is working fine now.